# Redirection operator in UNIX

Tags: shell, redirect, unix

Suppose I have three files file1 file2 file3 having some content
Now when I do this on shell prompt `cat file1 > file2 >file3`

Content of file1 is copied to file3 and file2 becomes empty

Similarly when I do `cat > file1 > file2 > file3`
It ask for input and this input is stored in file3 and both file1 and file2 are empty

and also for `cat > file1 > file2 < file3` contents of file3 is copied to file2 and file1 is empty.

Can someone please explain to me what is happening I am new to UNIX. Also any website where I can learn more about these redirection operators.

Thanks

Comment: Since this is largely invalid syntax, it's hard to explain.  You should only use one `>` or `<` operator.  Using two is a mistake, which makes it hard to explain.  Have you read `man bash` to read about the shell?  Have you tried reading any of thousands of `bash` and `shell` tutorials that are available?  Please (1) read a shell tutorial and then (2) update your question based on what you learned.  Here's the first google hit: http://gd.tuwien.ac.at/linuxcommand.org/lts0060.html.  Start here.

Comment: Redirection operators < > >> <<< >& ...  http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html

Answer (score 8):

Consider how the shell processes each part of the command as it parses it:

```
cat file1 > file2 >file3
```

1. `cat file1`: prepare a new process with the `cat` program image with argument `file1`. ( given 1 or more arguments, `cat` will read from each argument as a file and write to its output file descriptor)
2. `> file2`: change the new process' output file descriptor to write to `file2` instead of the current output sink (initially the console for an interactive shell) - create `file2 if necessary.
3. `> file3`: change the new process' output file descriptor to write to `file3` instead of the current output sink (was `file2`) - create `file3` if necessary
4. `End of command`: Spawn the new process

So in the end, `file2` is created, but unused.  `file3` gets the data.

```
cat > file1 > file2 > file3
```

1. `cat`: prepare a new process with the `cat` program/image with no arguments. (given no arguments, `cat` will read from its input file descriptor and write to its output file descriptor)
2. `> file1`: change the new process' output file descriptor to write to `file1` instead of the current output sink (initially the console for an interactive shell) - create `file1` if necessary.
3. `> file2`: change the new process' output file descriptor to write to `file2` instead of the current output sink (was `file1`) - create `file2` if necessary.
4. `> file3`: change the new process' output file descriptor to write to `file3` instead of the current output sink - (was `file2`) create `file3` if necessary
5. `End of command`: Spawn the new process

So in the end, `file1` and `file2` are created, but unused.  `file3` gets the data. `cat` waits for input on its input device (the console device as default for an interactive shell). Any input that `cat` receives will go to its output device (which ends up being `file3` by the time the shell finished processing the command and invoked `cat`).

```
cat > file1 > file2 < file3
```

1. `cat`: prepare a new process with the `cat` program/image with no arguments. (given no arguments, `cat` will read from its input file descriptor and write to its output file descriptor)
2. `> file1`: change the new process' output file descriptor to write to `file1` instead of the current output sink (initially the console for an interactive shell) - create `file1` if necessary.
3. `> file2`: change the new process' output file descriptor to write to `file2` instead of the current output sink (was `file1`) - create `file2` if necessary.
4. `< file3`: change the new process' input file descriptor to read from `file3` instead of the current input source (initially the console for an interactive shell)
5. `End of command`: Spawn the new process

So in the end, `file1` is created, but unused.  `file2` gets the data. `cat` waits for input on its input device (which as set to `file3` by the time the shell finished processing the command and invoked `cat`). Any input that `cat` receives will go to its output device (which ends up being `file2` by the time the shell finished processing the command and invoked `cat`).

--

Note that in the first example, `cat` is the one who processes/opens `file1`. The shell simply passed the word `file1` to the program as an argument.  However, the shell opened/created `file2` and `file3`.  `cat` knew nothing about `file3` and has no idea where the stuff it was writing to its standard output was going.

In the other 2 examples, the shell opened all the files.  `cat` knew nothing about any files.  `cat` had no idea where its standard input was coming from and where its standard output was going to.

---

Per @Sorpigal comment - the [BASH manual](http://gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html) has some good descriptions of what the different redirection operators do.  Much of it is the same across different Unix shells to varying degrees, but consult your specific shell manual/manpage to confirm. Thanks @Sorpigal.

http://gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html

Comment: The bash manual covers a lot of this pretty well, under REDIRECTION.

Comment: @Sorpigal - True - http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html - is useful, even though the OP didn't say they are using `bash` (or even `Bourne shell) specifically.  The point wasn't to expain what the redirection operators do, but rather to give a narrative about how the commands are being processed.  For a newbie having trouble understanding what's happening, a step-by-step description is a big help (especially if its their own examples).  Now that they have this mental model of how this works, the manual can give the details.

Comment: I agree, your writeup is directly useful and is far clearer than just reading REDIRECTION. I certainly find no fault, which is why I upvoted. It's just a good idea to include references to the actual docs for further reading.

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect the standard input `<` standard output `1>` or `>` error output `2>` or both outputs `&>` but you can only redirect 1:1, you can't redirect one output into two different files.

What you are looking for is the `tee` utility.

Comment: How this explains why `file2` is empty and `file3` contains data from `file`?

Comment: Well, in your shell the redirection is simply overridden, therefore `> file2` is probably being completely ignored, but that is shell specific.

Comment: `file2` doesn't seem to be ignored, because it is created and is empty. Very interesting.

Comment: @khachik Oh well, shell specific stuff.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to lose original content, you should use *redirect and append* `>>` or `<<` operators instead. You can read more [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html).